# jQuery does not trigger any function which i wrote

Tags: jquery

I'm used jQuery 1.10 in a html page. But this very basic codes are not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_theme/cupios/js/jQuery-dev-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".rad2 span").click(function(){

            console.log($(this));

        });

    });
</script>
```

The include path is correct. And when i write this code on the Firebug or Chrome Developer Tool it working very good. Where is my problem? In browsers or another? Because these codes working is correct !

Comment: looks like a dynamic element

Comment: ouv yes i that's a dynamic element and does not access. 
 $(document).on('click', ".rad2 span", function (){}); solved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since the code is working from console, I think the elements are created dynamically(after the dom ready handler is triggered).

So try to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".rad2 span", function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

It looks like when the dom ready handler is executed the target elements are not present in the dom so the handler is not getting attached to them

Comment: Always consider to comment on downvote if it is not obvious what the error is, thx!